# Bazaar: Do I need branches?

Tags: version-control, branch, bazaar, vcs-checkout

I'm new to VCS and I'm just trying to get my head around how to use Bazaar for my situation. My situation is that I'm a solo web developer working on a web site that consists of a live website e.g. www.mysite.com and a staging/development site e.g. dev.mysite.com. I'm using Bazaar Explorer as I'm not really a command line type of guy. I just work from one main computer and I upload the files to the web server by FTP. I have Bazaar installed on my local Windows computer.

So to get started I created a Bazaar project on my local computer. I stuck with the default 'Feature branches' option since Bazarr documentation says that this is best for small projects (but I don't fully grasp the difference between the workspace models even after reading the docs). This created a folder (which I called _Source Control) with sub folders trunk and .bzr. I copied all my project files (i.e. the website files) into trunk and did an initial commit.

Now my first question is **should I just work directly on these files or do I need to make another branch to work on?**

Is this workflow a sensible approach or is there an obviously better way?:

- Work on some files in the main trunk
- FTP the updated files to the staging site as I work to check for errors, functionality, etc.
- Once I've reached a point where I've completed a certain piece of functionality, commit my changes
- Upload the latest revision to the live website using the bzr-upload plugin

Then how should I handle the situation where I discover that the latest update has introduced a problem and I want to roll the website back to the previous revision? Is it like this:

- revert to previous version in Bazaar
- Upload this revision to the live website using the bzr-upload plugin
- then how do I get back to the latest version so that I can work on fixing the issue? Is this where I would need a branch?
- once I've updated the files again to fix the issue, do a commit and upload the latest revision to the live website using the bzr-upload plugin

And a final question, is Checkout relevent at all in my situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Feature branches` option of Bazaar Explorer creates a so-called **Shared Repository** and a single branch called `trunk` inside it (called a **Repository Tree**). In your example:

- `_Source Control` == **Shared Repository**
- `_Source Control/trunk` == **Repository Tree**

The idea is that in this setup you can create multiple branches next to `trunk`, and they will store revision data efficiently, by sharing stuff in the shared repository, to put it in a nutshell.

If you are a beginner, then don't worry about branches. At some point it will probably naturally come to you. For example you realize you want to do something experimental but you don't want to mess up your trunk. The obvious solution will be to create a branch.

Now about your workflow:

- I think you can use the `bzr upload` plugin for both the staging site and the live site.
- To roll back your live site to a previous version, use `bzr upload -rREV --overwrite` where `REV` is the revision you want to rollback to. Using the `--overwrite` there looks dirty, and it probably is. But that's the only way it works for me, I think it's a bug in my version of the plugin (`1.0.1dev`), I suggest to try first without that flag.
- To fix the bug, no need to roll back locally, just fix the bug and confirm it, then upload again with `bzr upload` without the other flags to bring the website up to the latest version.

There are many ways of working with Bazaar. You can implement a beautiful and sophisticated workflow, or use this somewhat dirty but simple and easy to understand workflow. Let me know if you have further problems.

And no, you don't need `checkout` in the setup you described.

Comment: Very helpful answer. I like the idea of your solution for reverting the live site to previous version using bzr-upload, I hadn't even thought it could be used to upload an earlier revision. That keeps things simple as it doesn't involve spawning off any new branches. I'm still not sure though about using bzr-upload to update the staging site as I tend to do lots of incremental updates of just 1 or 2 files when I'm working on something and I may also have 1 or 2 other files in a broken state at the same time so FTPing individual files seems better to me - at least that's what I'm used to.

Comment: If you want to update just 1-2 files via FTP, you have to select the individual files manually, whereas `bzr upload` is a just one simple command, so I don't see how FTP would be easier. Using `bzr upload` consistently will also ensure consistency between your local env and the beta site. Btw, if you have ssh access to your sites then use bzr+ssh:// style URLs instead of ftp:// for more efficient (and secure) transfers

Comment: FileZilla is what I'm used to but I might try it out for uploading to staging and see how it goes. Am i correct to assume i dont need to do a commit prior to calling `bzr upload` to upload the latest modified files?

Comment: You need to commit. Uncommitted changes will not be uploaded. I think that's a good thing.

Comment: In that case it suits me better to stick to uploading to staging with Filezilla as I tend to make lots of little tweaks to files and upload so that I can see what's going on. So I would not want to be commiting each of these little incremental changes especially since they will often be in a broken state.

Comment: While I don't see why you cannot test those little incremental changes locally before uploading, *if* that's indeed the case then I agree, manually uploading is better than polluting the commit history with meaningless changes

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking. By the way I don't test locally because I don't set up a local test enviornment - the staging website is my test enviornment.

Answer (score 2):

In Bazaar, a single branch is a linear history of your project files. You need multiple branches as soon as you want to work on multiple versions of your project concurrently. That naturally happens when multiple developers are involved, but can also be useful for one-person projects.

For example, it allows you to continue to develop a new feature as part of a feature branch, while adding, testing, and deploying bug fixes on the main branch. Once the feature is finished, it can then be merged back into the main branch. Similarly, if you want to experiment with something that you may or may not want to have as part of your main codebase, it is a good idea to have an experimental branch for that.

For simple projects, a single main branch may be all you need, but it is a good idea to familiarize yourself with branching regardless, as it has a number of very practical use cases.

In order to deal with the "problem" scenario you describe: First, get the last working revision that you have. There are a number of ways to accomplish that:

- `bzr checkout` can be used to create a new checkout of a specific branch and revision in a different working directory. You then have a directory containing the old version and a directory containing the new version.
- `bzr branch` does largely the same thing as `bzr checkout` for this purpose, but also creates an independent branch in the new directory based off the specified revision. This is useful if, as described above, you need to work on both the old and the new version concurrently.
- `bzr update` can be used to switch the current directory to a different revision. You can then do whatever you want to deploy the old version and use `bzr update` again to switch back to the most recent one.

Comment: This helps my understanding. Thanks for listing the 3 options for dealing with the problem scenario. I think the bzr update is the easiest option.

Comment: Actually, you should merge the main (trunk) branch into your new feature branch. Test the new feature branch again to make sure it works with the fixes you made in main. Then merge the new feature branch back into the main.